# Change "Your post appears to contain code"-message to an ignorable warning

Tags: feature-request, editor

I just tried to answer a question, but sadly the editor didn't let me submit my answer. After searching here for the issue I found out that there were some other people who had the same problem. Sadly this didn't result in correcting the feature but in correcting the people...

- [I'm getting "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" When there's no code in the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126236)
- ["Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code." - Not a single line of code was written that day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148089)
- [Incomprehensible "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113810)
- [Mystified by: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148010)
- [Bug in "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" heuristic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130736)

If changing or improving the detection algorithm to prevent triggering the message in cases like these is not an option, why not change to message to a type which the user can ignore if he is sure that there is no code in his answer?

Comment: Any chance you could show us what you tried to submit that caused the message to appear?

Comment: It was the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310552 and thx to this meta-post I seem to have gained some minus votes... (the question is some days old but didn't receive a minus vote before...)

Comment: I was hoping you could share a "before" version. If anything it might have helped identify what the filter choked on and perhaps that could be addressed.

Comment: the before version didn't have the bullets in front of the links

Comment: @Bart btw. when I posted this I thought the links provided enough examples to find examples to improve the algorithm

Comment: Listen, I'm trying to constructively address the issue you faced by trying to figure out what your issue was. Especially when you yourself say that all of your the links in this question had other solutions than the one you applied, it's good to know that the situation was.

Comment: @Bart thx, sorry I'm just a little frustrated. This was the original message: http://pastebin.com/DQ1FUttg

Comment: I'd say it simply shouldn't have choked on that. Perhaps your "arrow" was interpreted to be code-like. In any case, if your feature request doesn't make it, this case might well serve as some good information for a little tweak.

Answer (score 12):

> If changing or improving the detection algorithm to prevent triggering the message in cases like these is not an option, why not change to message to a type which the user can ignore if he is sure that there is no code in his answer?

Because then there would be thousands of people posting code without properly formatting it.  Many people won't even read such an error message without clicking through, and of those that do, many will still click through rather than taking the time to fix the problem (because in most cases they really will have code not properly formatted).

You've found half a dozen people having problems over the course of two years, yet there are dozens of people posting code without formatting it every day.  That's a pretty decent margin of error in my mind.  I think that is a small enough false positive rate that it can be handled as it is currently.  If this becomes a more widespread problem and the filter itself cannot be improved then the issue can be re-addressed.

Comment: and why not changing the message to somthing meaningful? I finally fixed it by putting bulletpoints in front of my links but all the other had problems with whitespaces (missing linebreak, too many linebreaks)...

Comment: I mostly agree with this, but if this is not worth a fix, a dev should at least explain why it happens and how to avoid or work around the issue.

Comment: @JepZ What do you propose changing the wording too?  Keep in mind the idea is that your post managed to hit a filter indicating there was code not properly formatted as code.  It's possible that it was indeed a false positive and you didn't have unformatted code, in which case a small change that seemingly wouldn't be relevant could change the post enough to not hit the filter, but I don't see how the error message should be changed as a result of this.  If it was known to be a false positive it just wouldn't filter it at all.

Comment: btw. I'm not sure if your statistic is right, because you don't know how many people failed to answer a question and didn't know about Meta or weren't alllowed to post here

Comment: @JepZ While that's true, I still don't see this as a serious issue as there really are so few people who have brought it up here.  I of course realize that it doesn't represent *everyone* with this problem.

Comment: Btw. nobody came back on fixing the orginal issue... funny. Instead we discuss about statistics which are wrong or don't exist. Most web-developers fight for every single new customer. Not so at SO. Here are new people not so rare, since there are enough experienced ones... I know that it is important to have high-quality answers but wasn't that exactly the reason to introduce the upvoting system? to upvote the good answers an let the bad ones down?

Comment: @JepZ The model that SO follows, and the reason it has been so successful, is that SO does everything it can to get high quality answerers, and it does what it needs to in order to keep them happy and to allow them to post quality answers to questions that they are likely to find interesting.  It does *not* go out of its way to assist people asking questions at the expense of the experts who answer them.  It is under the assumption that people who have a problem they want solved for free by an expert will jump through the hoops they have to to get their answer.  This has proven correct.

Comment: @JepZ You'll notice the sites that don't apply restrictions or expectations on those asking questions, instead leaving those who answer them to deal with all of the problems that they create, have been virtually starved to death by SO.  The true experts don't go to those places anymore, they go to SO, so anyone who wants a solution to their problem also goes to SO, because that's where the experts are.

Comment: So many experts but the newbe who points out a weakness in the system and makes a (wrong) suggestion to improve the system gets away with -4 point (until now)...

Comment: @JepZ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @JepZ Those people seem to feel that the current filter adds more benefit than the problems it causes, and voted accordingly.  Note that [votes are a little different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: @Servy So many experts... they downvoted my original question and didn't leave a comment why. So I dont even know what to improve. The poor timing was that they downvoted (twice) right after I posted my suggestion here...

Comment: @JepZ, I think it was probably just a down-vote spree sort of mentality. A lot of times someone will post something on meta, and if their meta post gets downvoted, people will sometimes without thinking downvote the example question as well (and similarly, some people that upvote meta questions will non-thinkingly upvote the linked example). Personally, I thought your question and answer were both good, so I upvoted them both. And as voting on meta works differently, I downvoted this meta question, because I disagree with the proposal, not because I think it was a bad question.

Comment: @Ben Lee Thank you for clarification :-)

Comment: Joining the army of angry users. This error blocked my post but doesn't explain where error exactly ! I've spent a lot of time trying to fix it, but finally ended with bad formatted, but passed check, text. (My congratulations, is it what authors of engine tried to prevent from !)  You should either disable this engine feature, or extend it to show detailed analysis and exact problem in text. Here is my original "bad formatted" post: http://pastebin.com/u1M6eazz

Comment: I do not see how you can know this answer for sure, unless you have actually tried it. Have you? Have you had it be a warning that stops them from posting right away and tells them they need to fix it, but then also provides some way to override it, even if that means it goes to a queue where someone with high enough rep can verify it?

Comment: I'll also point out that this affects people answering questions just as much as it affects people asking questions. And that I definitely was more inclined to either find a workaround or delete my answer rather than actually report it. To be honest, I spent a long time on my answer, and so I was angry when there was no workaround. The text suggests there would be. You say "may contain code," and nothing about not being able to submit if you don't "fix" it. The first I realized it would keep me from submitting was when I clicked Submit. And, even then, I thought there'd be something I could do

Comment: Hence you can't tell by how many people report issue. Unless you are tracking how often that error appears and checking how often the heuristic fails, I can't see how you have accurate data on this. Sure, it's not a majority, probably, but it might be higher than you'd expect, and thus something to work on.

Comment: @trlkly You've just proved my point for me.  You had a poorly formatted post and your immediate reaction was, "how do I subvert this message and submit my post anyway" rather than, "how do I fix the problem with my post so that it no longer has this problem".  Clearly you'd have just submitted an improperly formatted post anyway if you were given the option to do so, and only contemplated fixing it when you *didn't* have such an option.

Comment: Do not make up stuff I didn't say. That is insulting.  My post was formatted correctly. I had even looked up on Meta how to do it properly, as I needed some special markup. That's why it took hours to compose. As I said, ***the algorithm can fail.*** The site admits as much in the warning. It uses the word "may." It "may" be improperly formatted, which means it "may" be properly formatted. And, FYI, I didn't contemplate fixing it. I looked for how to work around a bug. And, in doing so, I actually had to format the code so that it was not a proper code block. The algorithm made things worse.

Comment: @trlkly Assuming it's [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43749175/1159478) that's just not true.  You're trying to format your code as not code, rather than formatting your code as code.  If you format your code as code, as I've done, everything works perfectly fine.  So indeed you had an improperly formatted post in which you had code that wasn't formatted as code, and all you did was search for ways to subvert the check, rather than actually formatting your code as code.