# Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code (again)

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, code-formatting

I stumbled upon this error while writing https://stackoverflow.com/a/29850739/4486184

The problem was that I was missing a newline between the "==========" and the following code but the preview showed it as alright:

> [image]

SO should change the preview so that it does NOT show everything as alright in that case, shouldn't it?

Should I make a bug report somewhere, use the contact form, or contact someone in particular?

Comment: This *is* a bug report. The [bug] tag is all you really need.

Comment: Posting bugs on Meta is pretty much all you need...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preview showed the right thing, the server would have rendered your post in the same way. The problem was that your "==========" itself was considered to be code by the detector, which was obviously nonsense. This issue is fixed and shouldn't happen anymore after the next build. Sorry about the confusion it caused you.